# How to remove ID3 tags fingerprint

Tags: php, mp3, vlc, id3, getid3

I changed **ID3 tags** in **mp3** file with **php getID3**.The changes made can be seen  in **VLC player** by right click on track and select the **information** option it shows the changes but when i click on **fingerprint** option it finds out the original tags.
My Question is that how can i **remove these tags completely** that the original ones can't be seen or recovered.